# How to send ASCII codes to serial port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

**Question :**

How to write/send ASCII codes to serial port in c#?

**Situation In-Depth :**

I have coded a software with takes results from a measuring device connected to the computer by RS232 port. I have a tare button on the measuring device which turns its display to 0.000 on press(i.e. Clears the reading). I have ASCII Codes for the same function(1BH+70H).

**What I have tried :**

```
SerialPort1.Write(1BH+70H);
```

But it returns no result.

**Required Output :**

I connect the device to serial port and open the serial port with required parameters. Then I click on a button on the window of my program. All digits on the display of the measuring device get cleared to zero(clicking on button sends command to device).

**Research :**

I spent a lot of time on the web searching answers to my problem but I could find nothing related to my question on the web. I got results about how to Write to serial port but not on how to write ASCII codes to serial port.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your code compiled successfully in C#?

The hexadecimal representation of your string is considered incorrect.

Try using `SerialPort1.Write("\x1B\x70")` or `SerialPort1.Write("\x1Bp")`.

If not, please specify Write in this way, specifying a byte array instead of a string as a parameter.
[Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Write_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_)